# Session variable not being saved from $_REQUEST

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I think i'm missing something obvious. I have a session started at the very top of my page. Below that i have the following code. The var dump out puts `"one"` when it is displayed from the requested page. After refresh the var dump out puts `NULL`. Why is this not getting saved?

```
if($_REQUEST["page"] == 1) {
    $_SESSION["one"] = true;
}

var_dump($_SESSION["one"]);
```

Comment: Where does the $_REQUEST["page"] variable come from?

Comment: Have you added session_start() before that?

Comment: it is part of the url `www.example.com/index.php?page=1`

Comment: Side note $_REQUEST is dangerous you should avoid it as much as possible or better not use it at all. because of the nature of the $_REQUEST because the value should come from $_POST OR $_GET OR $_COOKIE, very easy to be bypassed.

Comment: @Anigel `session_start()` is present before this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `session_start()` at the top of your page, as you claim, then your code should look something like this:

```
session_start();

if($_REQUEST["page"] == 1) {
    $_SESSION["one"] = true;
}

var_dump($_SESSION["one"]);
```

This should 100% work, no question. There IS something else stopping this from working in your code that you have not supplied. My first guess would be a session destroy of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure you start the session before attempting to use it. Secondly, it is recommended that you specify either POST or GET instead of generally using REQUEST. If you want to support either GET or POST, you might do something like this:

```
// Begin Session Management
session_start();

// Check both GET and POST for the parameter
if($_GET['page'] == 1 || $_POST['page'] ) {
    // Modify the session 
    $_SESSION["one"] = true;
}

// See what we ended up with in the session.
var_dump($_SESSION["one"]);
```

This works for me, but I'm using memcache as my session session handler. Verify your own session handler in php.ini, and ensure that the session handler is working properly. Also, ensure you are closing the session properly if you are redirecting, setting a new location, or exiting in unusual ways.

Comment: The OP says he included `session_start()` so then your code is exactly the same in terms of logic as what he currently has, that isn't working.

Comment: And yet somehow, an answer an hour later than mine, with the same code and slightly different words, got chosen as the "correct" answer.